# Parsing a string of a TFTP packet in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, tftp

I receive *TFTP packets* (read requests) using *recvfrom* with a *512 byte* buffer.

The string (file name to be transfered) starts at the third byte of the buffer. The first two are reserverd for the opcode.

I wrote the following function:

```
char * parseFileName(char * buffer){
    char * filename;

    for(int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
        *(filename + i) = buffer[i];

    *(filename + i) = '\0';

    return filename;
}
```

and I call it considering the opcode offset:

```
char * filename = parseFileName(buffer + 2);
```

However, this doesn't work and the program stops:

```
printf("%s", filename);
```

Unless I add this:

```
printf("\n");
```

right before the return statement in the parseFileName function. Only then I can print the filename string on the calling function.

**Why is that happening ?**

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for `filename` to point to.

Comment: BTW, your loop can be replaced with `strcpy(filename, buffer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not allocating any memory for `char* filename`.

If you know that string starts at buffer+2 and has `\0` terminator then you can directly do:

```
char* parseFileName(char* buffer) {
  return strdup(buffer);
}

char* fileName = parseFilename(buffer+2);
```

Mind that this requires a `free` when you are done with the file name.